# Windows 8 Metro: Implementing Validation

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, validation

I just googled for about 2 hours and didn't find anything.

Given the following scenario:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

How would you go about automatically get feedback of the validation on the UI like there is in MVC3?

(Oh, and I really don't care at the moment if I would be able to use the integrated DataAnnotations like [Required] or not)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I added something to the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/). It's called [TextBoxValidationExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8d621dbdff4d#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/TextBoxValidationExtensions.cs) and allows you to define the validation like this:

```
<TextBox
    Width="400"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    xyzc:TextBoxValidationExtensions.Format="NonEmptyNumeric"
    xyzc:TextBoxValidationExtensions.InvalidBrush="Red"
    xyzc:TextBoxValidationExtensions.ValidBrush="Green" />
```

The formats are currently defined as:

```
[Flags]
public enum ValidTextBoxFormats
{
    Any = 0,
    NonEmpty = 1,
    Numeric = 2,
    NonEmptyNumeric = 3
}
```

The entire code is a bit too long to share here. You can take out the code from CodePlex and modify to your liking - add new validation rules, modify default brushes etc.

Comment: It seems this does the trick! Anyway, can you explain me how I'd be able to set this up in code rather than in XAML?

Comment: If you are using MVVM then you would have some sort of view model for a field, with Text and Format properties, so then you would just set the binding like xyzc:TextBoxValidationExtensions.Format="{Binding Format}". If you just do code behind then you would call TextBoxValidationExtensions.SetFormat(myTextBox, ValidTextBoxFormats.Numeric).

Comment: Another solution was described by Jerry Nixon on his blog [here - Let’s Code! Handling validation in your Windows Store app](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-handling-validation-in-your.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just use events in the particular `XAML` control, like if in `textbox` use `pointerexited` and write a function in the code behind to perform the required validation.

Comment: Though the question was already answered: Your suggestion would lead to very much duplicated and difficult to maintain code. Filip Skakun has (in the accepted answer!) already answered perfectly. :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems, based on the support provided in the framework, that your extraordinary idea to "Validate" a text field is so rare and uncommon that it needs not to be considered at all. We all know that if what you wanted to do was at all common or useful, there would be some consideration for such a feature in such a well designed and comprehensive framework.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a need to validate a textbox, for let's say, an URL, Number, Basic EMail, or anything else? Of course you could do the validating on a click of a button and add the needed style to the textbox, but sometimes that's not what's needed. And also: just because it isn't in the framework doesn't mean it's not desired/needed.

Comment: @Shion find a dictionary and look up the word 'sarcasm'

Comment: +1 For the sarcasm - seems like the only thing left for .Net developers having to cope with all the missing obvious things in WinRT