# Implementing Validation on Windows 8 Metro Javascript application

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to add validation to my Javascript Metro app. In C#, it can be implemented nicely using WinRT XAML Toolkit as seen in
[Windows 8 Metro: Implementing Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620145/windows-8-metro-implementing-validation). How do I accomplish the same thing in Javascript without resorting to jQuery validation? I am avoiding jQuery validation since jQuery isn't recommended for Metro style apps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the default input control supports regex validation.

There is a good sample around validation, on MSDN:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/Form-controls-part-2-327288d9

While it's not completely wrapped up, it is something that is easy to build on.

Specifically, you are going to have to handle the oninvalid event, which doesn't seem to be described on MSDN, but is supported. This is raised when the regex that you supply doesn't match.

If you have deeper validation requirements, you'll either need to use JQuery (which should be fine -- theres no reason not to use it), or seek inspiration from that code to create your own methods for validation.

There are some helpful methods on the input controls that you're using that can help programmatically validate fields if you need to. Details on them can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Any examples? I don't see any effect after adding the pattern and title attributes

Comment: You're going to have to mostly roll your own. It looks like you're going to have to handle the oninvalid event, and use the other similar methods to those seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869710(v=vs.85).aspx