# Converting Xaml textbox to double, but how to validate that the user input is double not a string in c++ for the windows 8 app

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

This is what I have for my for my textbox in xaml.

```
<TextBox x:Name="number1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="85" Margin="115,239,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328" FontSize="60" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

This is what I have to get the text from the textbox:

```
void Simple_Calculator_4_Kids::MainPage::add_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
String^ str1 = txtNumberToMultiply->Text; 
wstring ws1( str1->Data());
wstringstream convertor; 
double ws1_d;
convertor << ws1; 
convertor >> ws1_d; 
ws1_d = ws1_d + 2.2; 
}
```

I don't understand how to add in a way to validate what's in the textbox is actually a double and not a string of letter or is empty.
How would I go upon doing adding a way to validate whats in the textbox to be a double? This is using C++ using visual studio 2012 for windows 8 app.

Comment: the http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/ may have what you need; take a look at the [thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620145/windows-8-metro-implementing-validation)

Comment: Unfortunately the toolkit is for .NET only, so it might not help too much other than the general approach.

Comment: Yea, it was not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use strtod from the C Run-Time Library (convert string to double-precision value). Per the documentation, test your text input against the function and check for error. strtod (and friends) are supported for Windows Store apps via C++ and CRT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out some about how the wstring keeps its input using char16 so I wrote this code. It just checks for periods and numbers.

```
bool isValidInput(String^ str){
    int decimalX = 0;
    wstring ws(str->Data());
    int strSize = ws.length();
    if(strSize<1)
        return false;
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<strSize;i++){
            if(ws[i]==46||ws[i]==48||ws[i]==49||ws[i]==50||ws[i]==51||ws[i]==52||ws[i]==53||ws[i]==54||ws[i]==55||ws[i]==56||ws[i]==57){
                if(ws[i]==46){
                    decimalX++;
                    if(decimalX>1)
                        return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```